# Changing the physical camera button control in android

Tags: android, camera

```
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keycode,KeyEvent event)
    {
     //check if the camera button is pressed
     if(keycode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CAMERA)
     {
         //if result
         if (mResultView.IsShowingResult)
         {
            mResultView.IsShowingResult = false;
         }
         else if (mCameraReadyFlag == true)//switch to camera view
         {
            mCameraReadyFlag = false;
            mPreview.camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);
         }


         return true;
     }
     return super.onKeyDown(keycode, event);
    }
```

I have the following code to check if the camera button is checked and if it is,then take a picture.But it uses the physical camera button code.I want to take a picture if the screen is pressed since camera buttons are now out of fashion.Can you give me equivalent function for the same please.

Comment: just anywhere on the screen? Are you sure?

Comment: I mean like how we normally take picture by pressing on the screen.

Comment: Define a button in your layout, and set its "onClick" property to "onCameraClick", where `public void onCameraClick(View view) {…}` calls **mPreview.camera.takePicture()**

Comment: I dont want to use a button.I just want to take a picture by clicking on the screen.

Comment: Then create a transparent "button" that will cover the whole screen

Comment: @AlexCohn How to do that?Can you please explain it or provide me some links to tutorials.